Using libclang, is there a way to know if a closure type was introduced in the context of the initialization of a inline variable?
Given the following C++ code:
inline auto v = []{ return 1; }();

The context of the closure type is the initializer of an inline variable. This leads to a special mangling rule in the Itanium ABI (mentioned here).
When libclang visit the CXXRecordDecl corresponding to this closure type, is there a way to know if we are in this special context?

Look for declaration of v instead of the lambda to get the context first?

Turns out libtooling has a special function CXXRecordDecl::getLambdaContextDecl, which can be used to solve the problem:
if (decl->isLambda()) {
    const clang::Decl *context = getLambdaContextDecl(decl);
    if (const auto *varDecl =
            llvm::dyn_cast_or_null<const clang::VarDecl>(context))
    {
        if (varDecl->isInline()) [...]


Use CXXRecordDecl::getLambdaContextDecl
As the question is specifically about the situation where the Itanium ABI name mangling is affected by the lambda context, the CXXRecordDecl::getLambdaContextDecl() is the answer.  That will return the context variable in the relevant contexts.  This requires using the C++ API though, as it is not exposed in the C API.  (Credit to OP for pointing this out in a comment.  I had overlooked its relevance.)
The rest of this answer was based on misreading the question, thinking the goal was simply to recognize a lambda in a variable initializer.  It might be useful for someone wanting to do that, but is unnecessary for the task in this question.

What does the AST look like?
To start, let's look at the AST for the input:
inline auto v = []{ return 1; }();

Run the command clang++ -fsyntax-only -Xclang -ast-dump test.cc.  The
output will be something like:
TranslationUnitDecl 0x56461ab90ec8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc>
|-TypedefDecl 0x56461ab91730 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __int128_t '__int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x56461ab91490 '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x56461ab917a0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __uint128_t 'unsigned __int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x56461ab914b0 'unsigned __int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x56461ab91b18 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __NSConstantString '__NSConstantString_tag'
| `-RecordType 0x56461ab91890 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|   `-CXXRecord 0x56461ab917f8 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|-TypedefDecl 0x56461ab91bb0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __builtin_ms_va_list 'char *'
| `-PointerType 0x56461ab91b70 'char *'
|   `-BuiltinType 0x56461ab90f70 'char'
|-TypedefDecl 0x56461abd7dd8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __builtin_va_list '__va_list_tag[1]'
| `-ConstantArrayType 0x56461abd7d80 '__va_list_tag[1]' 1 
|   `-RecordType 0x56461ab91ca0 '__va_list_tag'
|     `-CXXRecord 0x56461ab91c08 '__va_list_tag'
|-VarDecl 0x56461abd7ea0 <test.cc:4:1, col:33> col:13 v 'int':'int' inline cinit
| `-ExprWithCleanups 0x56461abd8b50 <col:17, col:33> 'int':'int'
|   `-CXXOperatorCallExpr 0x56461abd8978 <col:17, col:33> 'int':'int' '()'
|     |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x56461abd8908 <col:32, col:33> 'auto (*)() const -> int' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
|     | `-DeclRefExpr 0x56461abd8888 <col:32, col:33> 'auto () const -> int' lvalue CXXMethod 0x56461abd8140 'operator()' 'auto () const -> int'
|     `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x56461abd8960 <col:17, col:31> 'const (lambda at test.cc:4:17)' lvalue <NoOp>
|       `-MaterializeTemporaryExpr 0x56461abd8948 <col:17, col:31> '(lambda at test.cc:4:17)' lvalue
|         `-LambdaExpr 0x56461abd8720 <col:17, col:31> '(lambda at test.cc:4:17)'
|           |-CXXRecordDecl 0x56461abd7ff8 <col:17> col:17 implicit class definition
|           | |-DefinitionData lambda pass_in_registers empty standard_layout trivially_copyable literal can_const_default_init
|           | | |-DefaultConstructor defaulted_is_constexpr
|           | | |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
|           | | |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit
|           | | |-CopyAssignment trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
|           | | |-MoveAssignment
|           | | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial
|           | |-CXXMethodDecl 0x56461abd8140 <col:18, col:31> col:17 used constexpr operator() 'auto () const -> int' inline
|           | | `-CompoundStmt 0x56461abd8398 <col:19, col:31>
|           | |   `-ReturnStmt 0x56461abd8388 <col:21, col:28>
|           | |     `-IntegerLiteral 0x56461abd81f8 <col:28> 'int' 1
|           | |-CXXConversionDecl 0x56461abd85a8 <col:17, col:31> col:17 implicit constexpr operator int (*)() 'auto (*() const noexcept)() -> int' inline
|           | |-CXXMethodDecl 0x56461abd8660 <col:17, col:31> col:17 implicit __invoke 'auto () -> int' static inline
|           | `-CXXDestructorDecl 0x56461abd8748 <col:17> col:17 implicit referenced ~(lambda at test.cc:4:17) 'void () noexcept' inline default trivial
|           `-CompoundStmt 0x56461abd8398 <col:19, col:31>
|             `-ReturnStmt 0x56461abd8388 <col:21, col:28>
|               `-IntegerLiteral 0x56461abd81f8 <col:28> 'int' 1
`-CXXRecordDecl 0x56461abd7ff8 <col:17> col:17 implicit class definition
  |-DefinitionData lambda pass_in_registers empty standard_layout trivially_copyable literal can_const_default_init
  | |-DefaultConstructor defaulted_is_constexpr
  | |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
  | |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit
  | |-CopyAssignment trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
  | |-MoveAssignment
  | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial
  |-CXXMethodDecl 0x56461abd8140 <col:18, col:31> col:17 used constexpr operator() 'auto () const -> int' inline
  | `-CompoundStmt 0x56461abd8398 <col:19, col:31>
  |   `-ReturnStmt 0x56461abd8388 <col:21, col:28>
  |     `-IntegerLiteral 0x56461abd81f8 <col:28> 'int' 1
  |-CXXConversionDecl 0x56461abd85a8 <col:17, col:31> col:17 implicit constexpr operator int (*)() 'auto (*() const noexcept)() -> int' inline
  |-CXXMethodDecl 0x56461abd8660 <col:17, col:31> col:17 implicit __invoke 'auto () -> int' static inline
  `-CXXDestructorDecl 0x56461abd8748 <col:17> col:17 implicit referenced ~(lambda at test.cc:4:17) 'void () noexcept' inline default trivial

We are interested in the CXXRecordDecl node.  In the output above,
there is only one such node, at address 0x56461abd7ff8, although it
appears twice due to a quirk in how -ast-dump works.  (Basically,
there is a non-tree edge, and -ast-dump does not compensate for that.)
The chain of most immediate interest is:
|-VarDecl 0x56461abd7ea0 <test.cc:4:1, col:33> col:13 v 'int':'int' inline cinit
[...]
|         `-LambdaExpr 0x56461abd8720 <col:17, col:31> '(lambda at test.cc:4:17)'
|           |-CXXRecordDecl 0x56461abd7ff8 <col:17> col:17 implicit class definition

That is, our CXXRecordDecl is a child of LambdaExpr, which is a
descendant of the VarDecl representing the declaration of v.  The
goal, then, is to recognize that pattern in the AST.
Recognizing with clang-query
clang-query
is a command line tool that uses an
AST Matcher Language
to locate elements of interest.  The following shell script has an AST
matcher that recognizes the pattern we are after:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$HOME/opt/clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin:$PATH

query='m

  varDecl(
    hasInitializer(
      expr(
        hasDescendant(
          lambdaExpr(
            hasDescendant(
              cxxRecordDecl().bind("lambdaRecord")
            )
          ).bind("lambda")
        )
      )
    )
  ).bind("decl")

'

if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 filename.cc -- <compile options like -I, etc.>"
  exit 2
fi

# Run the query.  Setting 'bind-root' to false means clang-query will
# not also print a redundant "root" binding.
clang-query \
  -c="set bind-root false" \
  -c="$query" \
  "$@"

# EOF

When run on the example input, the output is:
$ ./cmd.sh test.cc --

Match #1:

$PWD/test.cc:4:1: note: "decl" binds here
inline auto v = []{ return 1; }();
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$PWD/test.cc:4:17: note: "lambda" binds here
inline auto v = []{ return 1; }();
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$PWD/test.cc:4:17: note: "lambdaRecord" binds here
inline auto v = []{ return 1; }();
                ^
1 match.

This doesn't directly answer the question, but it at least validates the
basic idea, and could be useful for prototyping.
Recognizing with the C++ API
When using the C++ API, known as "libtooling", one can use essentially
the same matcher language.  The details are explained in the
tutorial.
Alternatively, one can traverse the AST directly, perhaps using
RecursiveASTVisitor,
looking for the features of interest:

VarDecl
has getInit()
to get the initializer.

LambdaExpr
has getLambdaClass()
to get the class that represents the closure.

CXXRecordDecl
has isLambda()
(and several related methods) to mark closure class declarations.
However, it does not have a pointer back to the LambdaExpr.


Using these methods, together with an AST traversal that maintains some
sort of state about where it is in the AST, and perhaps some auxiliary
maps, one can recognize the desired pattern.
Recognizing with the C API
Here is where, unfortunately, things become difficult, and hence this is
only a partial answer.  The C API only exposes a small, idiosyncratic
fraction of what is available in the C++ API, and does so in an
ambiguous way.  Instead of things like
VarDecl::getInit() and
LambdaExpr::getLambdaClass(), there is only
clang_visitChildren,
which visits all the children but does not differentiate between them by
role.  The initializer of a VarDecl might be the first child in a
simple scenario but the 5th child in a more complicated example (the
types used in the type specifier and declarator can also be children if
they are sufficiently "interesting"), and likewise for LambdaExpr.
This is the "final straw" reason I eventually gave up on using the C
API: at a certain point, heuristically inferring the role of children
simply becomes unsustainably fragile.
Furthermore, CXXRecordDecl::isLambda is not exposed.  The only
accessor specific to CXXRecordDecl is
clang_CXXRecord_isAbstract(),
corresponding to
CXXRecordDecl::isAbstract().
If you want to know any other details (other than enumerating children),
you're out of luck.
Depending on what you're trying to do, the above may suffice.  Just like
with the C++ API, you have the ability to traverse the AST (albeit
without child differentiation) and apply filter logic as you go.
If the above is not sufficiently precise, the C++ API is the alternative
I would recommend.  It's a lot less pleasant to develop against due to
very slow recompilation times (20s per file instead of 0.2s), but it has
nearly everything you'd want to know, and is reasonably well organized.
For completeness, I'll note that
python libclang is just a Python
wrapper around the C API, so has all of the same problems.

Thanks for your answer. It seems like getLambdaContextDecl from CXXRecordDecl is the droid I'm looking for. If it doesn't work, I'll accept your answer.

@Dorian You're right, that function should do what you want (it does in this example).  I misunderstood the question originally, sorry!
